# How to append the current list with another element in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Let's say I have a list:
`a b a a a c e`.
I want to get rid of all adjacent duplicate, i.e. the two a's in the middle. So the list becomes
`a b a c e`.

The algorithm that I current have in mind is,
- Check if the current value is equal to the next value by

```
(equal? (car lst) (car (cdr lst)))
```

If they are equal then I want to skip the duplicate element, but I don't know how to achieve this behavior in Scheme? Any idea?
- If they're not equal, keep traversing through the list.

By the way, is there a way to implement iterative `for` loop in Scheme for these types of problem? Because I feel recursion is just overkill for this simple problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Scheme has no `for` loop by default. But SRFI 1 provides `fold`, which is the standard way to iteratively compress a list to a single value. (There's also `map`, which is the standard way to process each element in a list, returning the results in a new list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an iterative answer for this problem using `fold`:

```
(define (uniq lst)
  (fold (lambda (elem result)
          (if (and (pair? result) (equal? elem (car result)))
              result
              (cons elem result)))
        '() (reverse lst)))
```

(In future, any time you're trying to convert a list to something, consider using `fold`, and any time you're trying to convert something to a list, consider using `unfold`. They're very powerful functions!)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Thanks for a nice solution. I will try to use `fold` from now on.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Hm, there are no `fold` and `unfold` in DrScheme. Do I need to include some libraries?

Comment: There are two flavors of 'fold' in DrRacket/DrScheme: foldl and foldr.  For 'unfold', I believe you'll have to go to SRFI-1. The meta-answer to your problem, though, is this: documentation! Try typing 'unfold' and hitting the F1 key; you should get a nice long help list.

Comment: @Chan: If you're following @John's suggestion to use `foldl` and `foldr` (which are the Racket names for `fold` and `fold-right` respectively), note that my solution uses `foldl` (since that's iterative). `foldr` is recursive, but allows you to remove the call to `reverse`.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Thank you. Wow, that's a lot of information. I'm a little confused because of the naming convention now. I've just learned Scheme for one day T_T!

Comment: @Chan: Functional programming has a steep learning curve, but once you learn it, you'll never look back. Good luck! :-D

Answer (score 2):

I have not written Scheme for a long time, but maybe this will be helpful to you:

```
(define (remove-adjacent-duplicates list)
    (if (empty? list)                    
        '()                              
        (if (equal? (car list) (cadr list))
            (remove-adjacent-duplicates (cdr list))
            (cons (car list) (remove-adjacent-duplicates (cdr list)))))
```

Oh, and don't be afraid of recursion, especially in Scheme. It's fun! :)

Comment: Oops, you need to check whether `(cdr lst)` is null, before you use `(cadr lst)`. :-)

Comment: @Robert Kolner: Thanks for the solution. In fact, the reason I studied Scheme is just Recursion, however it's a little strange for some circumstances where iteration is more meaningful. I don't want to be a recursive zealot, because it will affect my way of thinking in ordinary languages.

Comment: @Robert Kolner: There is no `cadr` in my DrScheme :(

Comment: That's right: functional programming is a VIRUS that will INFECT YOUR BRAIN. After learning to program in a functional language, using an imperative one will make you weep and cry. (Not actually joking all that much....)

Comment: @John: Iteration-vs-recursion is orthogonal to functional-vs-imperative. I often code functionally, but still prefer iteration (tail recursion) to straight-up recursion, when it suits the problem at hand. :-)

Comment: @Chris: I think we're in agreement on all but perhaps our choice of terms. In fact, I think that the emergence of list comprehension forms may soon render the iteration/recursion dichotomy totally obsolete. Racket's 'for', for instance, is both recursive and iterative.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would want to save the car of the cdr to cons onto the result of your recursive call (ditch the car, it makes checking in a case with like 3 a's easier). Now the question you are asking is what is the recursive call on. Well, now you cons the car of the cdr onto the recurion on the cdr.